# how do you get notes on chess moves, to save in Fritz?

Tags: fritz

how do you get notes on chess moves, to save in Fritz?

mine are not saving

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/crnjeNRSM8

For example

Say I add text here

[image]

But even after clicking save, if I reopen the game, it shows that the notes didn't save

How do I make sure it saves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do **File > Save > Save** it adds the game to the current database at the end. So scroll to the bottom of the database list of games, and you'll see those two games.

Instead, to save the game in place, you do **File > Save > Replace**, that "replaces" the current game with the one with your newly added notes.

It is counter-intuitive.